# How to ONLY display an image in the teaser for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm currently using a modified version of the Stark Theme, customized to what I need, on this site [tobyNews](http://www.tobynews.com). However, following some new design inspiration, I've decided that instead of showing text in the teaser I want to ONLY display an image. Each image would be displayed as a grid. What I need help on is getting the teaser to show just an image and not the title, date, or author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install and Enable Display Suite Module
2. Goto your teasers page, click the gear icon which appears on mouse hover on teaser and select manage display 
   [image]
3. on Manage Display page locate **Select a layout** option and select single column layout from drop down *(on selecting any layout the Title field will also be available to be manipulated by DS module other wise you wont be able to hide title field in manage display page )*
   [image]
4. You will see to headings Content and Disabled. Disable all the fields you don't want to display on teaser and drag image field in content.
   [image]
5. Now Save your display
6. Other things can be manipulate through CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module will give you this feature. It will give you advanced teaser-templates where you will be able to display one or multiple fields (and the option to display title or not) + you will get along quite easily!